# Create user, save data and THEN change the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a "Create user" function on my webpage. When creating the user it is simultaneously storing data the user wrote, such as name etc. After doing that the user should be presented with a page only for users, the problem is with my code that before the data of the user (name etc.) is stored, the user is being presented with a new page. How can I prevent that from happening?

My create user function:

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(function() {
  // User is created
  const imageUrl = "images/genericProfilePicture.png";
  const admin = false;
  const currentTime = timeStamp();

  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const userId = user.uid;


  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    address: address,
    zip: zip,
    city: city,
    department: department,
    membership: membership,
    admin: admin,
    added: currentTime,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });

  window.open('frontpage.php', '_top');


}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error has happened
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  alert(errorMessage);
});
```

Tried this code without any luck, no data stored and no new page shows:

```js
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        address: address,
        zip: zip,
        city: city,
        department: department,
        membership: membership,
        admin: admin,
        added: currentTime,
        profile_picture : imageUrl
       }).then(() => {
          window.open('frontpage.php', '_top');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**:

Just chain the `set()` with a `then()` block:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    address: address,
    zip: zip,
    city: city,
    department: department,
    membership: membership,
    admin: admin,
    added: currentTime,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  }).then(function(){
        window.open('frontpage.php', '_top');
    }) ...
```

**Option 2**: (if you actually need to verify some user details)

You can check that the user is added to the database, then show the window.

Something like:

```
function getUserStatus(uid) {
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.val() != null) {
            return snapshot.val().name;
        }
        return '';
    });
}
```

You can just chain this method in your code:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    address: address,
    zip: zip,
    city: city,
    department: department,
    membership: membership,
    admin: admin,
    added: currentTime,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });

getUserStatus(user.uid).then(function(name) {
    if (name !== '') {
       window.open('frontpage.php', '_top');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating stuff is asynchronous, and you are not listening the promise returned by e.g. the `.set()` that you are using. Thus, you're simply doing `window.open()` immediately after you start the update operation, so if the update takes a significant amount of milliseconds, which it always will, you're gonna end up loading the next page before the update is done.

So, as suggested in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), use the promise returned by `.set()` to determine when the update is done in the backend and only then direct the user to the next page. In practice, I'm guessing it should be as simple as putting the `window.open` in a `.then` block for the `.set`.

While it looks like you need to learn the basics of promises first before doing this kind of stuff (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises), I'm just gonna give you the template you should be using:

```
somethingsomething
  .set(...)
  .then( function{
    window.open(...);
  });
```

Comment: But I am already using a 'then' in creating the user function?

Comment: Yes, but nothing prevents you from nesting promises. (Obviously it could get nasty if you nest too many, but you've only got two).

Comment: I have edited the question with the code trying to use another then, but no data is stored and no new page is shown?

Comment: Are you using ES6? If not, the syntax is wrong in the other answer.

Comment: I honestly do not know. I am new to javascript, just trying to learn.

Comment: You're not, you would know if you were. Anyway, I've told you the answer and now you need to implement it, just put the `window.open` line in a `.then` block after the `.set` function. You've already managed to do it once with the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, just do what you did with that one.

Comment: Didn't I do that with the edited question? That is in a then block?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the syntax is wrong since you're not using ES6 which is a newer version of the language. There are no arrow functions in vanilla JS, browsers will not understand stuff like `=>` by themselves yet. See the block of code I added into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`set` also returns a promise so you need `.then` after that too

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId)
  .set()
  .then(() => {
    window.open('frontpage.php', '_top');
  });
```

Comment: I edited my question with your code, but no data is stored and no new page shows :(